# jq: How to display a value only if its key exists?

Tags: json, key, jq

I have the following json:

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "Description": "SG for ssh-proxy server",
            "GroupName": "ssh-proxy-SG",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "FromPort": 161,
                    "IpProtocol": "udp",
                    "IpRanges": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "ToPort": 161,
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "GroupId": "sg-22e04e44",
                            "UserId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                },
                {
                    "FromPort": -1,
                    "IpProtocol": "icmp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "ToPort": -1,
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "GroupId": "sg-4f1d8a35",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "ssh-proxy-SG"
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-d3131fbe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using `jq`, I'm trying to display such a list:

```
161 tcp sg-22e04e44
22 tcp 0.0.0.0/0
-1 icmp 0.0.0.0/0
```

I am able to print only the port and the protocol but not the ".IpRanges[].CidrIp", like so:

```
✗ aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-id sg-4f1d8a35 --profile XXXX --region us-east-1 --output json | jq -r '.SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[] | (.FromPort|tostring) + " " + .IpProtocol'
161 udp
22 tcp
-1 icmp
```

The problem is that sometimes (in this case the 161 udp rule) lacks ".IpRanges[].CidrIp" and it causes an error.

I tried this:

```
✗ aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-id sg-4f1d8a35 --profile XXXXXXX --region us-east-1 --output json | jq -r '.SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[] | (.FromPort|tostring) + " " + .IpProtocol + " " + .IpRanges[].CidrIp'

22 tcp 0.0.0.0/0
-1 icmp 0.0.0.0/0
```

But as you can see, the udp line is missing.

Also tried this:

```
✗ aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-id sg-4f1d8a35 --profile XXXXXXX --region us-east-1 --output json | jq -r '.SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[] | .IpRanges[]? |= if has(.CidrIp) then (.FromPort|tostring) + " " + .IpProtocol + " " + .IpRanges[].CidrIp else (.FromPort|tostring) + " " + .IpProtocol + " " + .UserIdGroupPairs[].GroupId end'

{
  "FromPort": 161,
  "IpProtocol": "udp",
  "IpRanges": [],
  "Ipv6Ranges": [],
  "PrefixListIds": [],
  "ToPort": 161,
  "UserIdGroupPairs": [
    {
      "GroupId": "sg-22e04e44",
      "UserId": "XXXXXXX"
    }
  ]
}
jq: error (at <stdin>:72): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you notice that `CidrIP` is not present for `udp` record

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention it, that’s my problem exactly

Comment: Do you want a empty string for that? How should your output look like?

Comment: 161 tcp sg-22e04e44
22 tcp 0.0.0.0/0
-1 icmp 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Ah, I thought that the // is a comment and didn't include it in my command, it works perfectly. Sorry for the misunderstanding, can you please return your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CidrIP` is not present for `udp` record. If you want to alternate between `.GroupId` and `CidrIp`, you can do an alternation like

```
.SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[] |
.FromPort as $port          |
.IpProtocol as $prot        |
.IpRanges as $ip            |
.UserIdGroupPairs as $group |
[
  ($port|tostring),
  ($prot),
  (select($ip|length) | $ip[].CidrIp) //
  (select($group|length) | $group[].GroupId) //
  empty
] |
@tsv
```

produces an output like you wanted

```
161 udp sg-22e04e44
22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0
-1  icmp    0.0.0.0/0
```

You can use the `--raw-output/-r` mode along with any of `@csv`, `@tsv` or `join(" ")` to represent the output in a tabular form.

[<sup>jqplay - Online demo</sup>](https://jqplay.org/s/Gk2ARJuOA1)

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do, in the udp rule, I'm trying to display ".UserIdGroupPairs.GroupId" if ".IpRanges[]" doesn't contain ".CidrIp" .

Comment: See edits. The code shown produces that exact output

Comment: Warning: Testing for whether or not a key exists can be done directly with `has/1` but not with `//` alone. The reason is that if FOO evaluates to a single value, say $foo, then `FOO // BAR` evaluates to BAR if $foo is false or null.

Comment: @peak: hope its better now

Comment: Hmm.  `jq -n '([],{},0,null) | select(length)'` yields:
[]
{}
0
null